# I want the length of counter after counting but it's showing all the numbers after counting.i want to print the length of values range from (10-20)

Tags: python, arrays

```
arr=[0,1,5,8,14,15,21,26]
count=0
For i in range(Len(arr)):
If(arr[i]>=10 and arr[i]<=20):Count+=1
Print(count)
```

I want the length of the values range between 10 and 20

Comment: This code is not "showing all the numbers". It's not doing anything because there are syntax errors. Please make sure the code you post in questions is actually runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code has a few syntax errors.
This should work:

```py
arr = [0,1,5,8,14,15,21,26]
count = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if (arr[i] >= 10 and arr[i] <= 20):
        count += 1
print(count)
```